# Large file processing in the web browser

Tags: encryption, filereader, chunks

I have to make encryption/decryption platform(maybe one page).
The UI/UX is similar to https://cryptii.com/
The technical challenge is that when I select large file(can be 1GB), we need to process file and the encrypted file must be downloaded.
Is it possible without sending file to the server?
I found out FileReader JS class can help reading files.
If possible, what's the best way to handle large file?
It is clear that to encrypt the file, we need to process every chunks.
Please let me know if there is a good idea.

I wanted to strategy to solve challenge.